# Testing if a messagebox was successfully shown in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, messagebox

hopefully it's pretty simple but I'm stuck trying to figure this out.

If I have a simple class with a method which is supposed to do something and then show a messagebox via MessageBox.Show("") when some values are in a certain state, how do I write a test/tests that can detect if a the messagebox was shown when expected and/or not shown when not expected?

Comment: I would hide showing the messagebox behind an interface. Then mock that interface and create a counter or something like that in your mock implementation.

Comment: That's *not* unit testing. That's UI testing. You can use the Accessibility API or Visual Studio's UI Test projects (which use the Accessibility API)

Comment: Can you please share your method which you want to test and potential unit test which you started to write?

Comment: @PatrickHofman that will test the counter though, not the message box and its contents.

Comment: Why can't you save that information too? It isn't too hard to create a list of 'shown messages' @Pan

Comment: @PatrickHofman you can save it but you can't test if the actual message was shown in the end.

Comment: You don't need to test the MessageBox.Show method since it is from the framework. You need to test if your code takes the correct path and passes the correct values to the Show() method. So the mock interface is the right way to go for a unit test.

Comment: @Dan it would be a *lot* better if you used MVVM or a similar pattern to separate the UI from your business code. This way you could ensure that the controller/model/whatever raised the proper notifications, and use far simpler UI/Integration testing to ensure that your UI shows the appropriate content in response to these notifications

Comment: @Dan if the method is quite large you have a *problem*. It *has* to be separated (and broken down too). Extract all UI references from it, otherwise you *can't* unit test it.

Comment: The method is actually quite large but in short it creates an object and initialises its variables using some entered information from a form thats already been validated. It then checks if a file exists and if it does pops a messagebox up to ask the user if they want to overwrite the file. I need to test first that the messagebox is shown when a file is there. then another test to make sure it doesnt come up and just saves immediately when there is no file already there. Then i need to test wether it overwrites or cancels correctly depending on the users choice.

Comment: @Dan don't. That's not unit testing or a testable design. Break the method in separate methods and test *them*. Use eg. the built-in `IProgress<T>` to send one-way messages to the UI. Create interfaces eg to *request* confirmations from the user, eg `IRequestOverwriteConfirmation` or something

Answer (score 3):

You can't really test that though Unit tests. There is an easy way to test if the code was called correctly though.

I would hide showing the `MessageBox` behind an interface. Then mock that interface and create a counter or something like that in your mock implementation. Of course you can make this as specific as you need, providing the message shown, etc.

Comment: A far better option is to use MVVM or a similar pattern to separate the UI from the backend code. You can unit test the controller/model whatever and use UI testing for the thin UI view

Comment: Of course, that would often require an entire rework of the program. This solution is easier to implement as a way to eventually use MVVM all the way.

Comment: The OP just mentioned in a comment that "the method is quite large". This means that it *has* to be unit tested independently of the UI. BTW. .NET already offers the `IProgress<T>` interface which offers both events and callbacks when an notification is raised. That makes unit testing a bit easier

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test that a MesssageBox appears, though it is possible to do so with one or another UI automation framework (like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx).

But it won't be a unittest. It would be an [automated UI test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726(v=vs.100).aspx).

So, if you want to create a proper unittest, then your class should be [injectable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with some

```
public interface IMessageBox
{
    void Show(String message);
}

public class SUT
{
    public SUT(IMessageBox messageBox)
    {   
        this._messageBox = messageBox;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        this._messageBox.Show("TEST);
    }
}
```

So that you can [mock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx) that IMessageBox inside the unittest.

For example, with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var messageBox = new Mock<IMessageBox>();
    messageBox
        .Setup(m =>
            m.Show("TEST))
        .Verifiable();

    var sut = new SUT(messageBox.Object);

    // Act
    sut.Test();

    // Verify
    messageBox.Verify();        
}
```

Comment: .NET already provides the `IProgress` interface. Furthermore, an interface should *not* be tied to its implementation, like `IMessageBox`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right that decoupling that class from UI responsibilities with more generic `IProgress` mediator may be a good idea. Though that depends on the actual system. But I don't understand the part about "tied to its implementation"? The only way `IMessageBox` is tied to its implementation is by its name and that can be changed. No one prevents anyone from implementing some ConsoleMessageBox like `Console.WriteLine(message); Console.ReadKey();`. `IMessageBox` has clear responsibility - it is just that such interface shouldn't probably be used deep inside business logic.